# Iterative algorithm and functional code (Dafny)

Tags: dafny

I have this simple algorithm + functions:

```
method DifferenceMinMax(a: array<int>) returns (diff: int)
    requires a.Length > 0
    ensures diff == (Max(a[..]) - Min(a[..]))
{
    var minVal := a[0];
    var maxVal := a[0];

    for i := 1 to a.Length
        invariant 1 <= i <= a.Length
        invariant minVal <= maxVal
        invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < i ==> minVal <= a[k] && a[k] <= maxVal
    {
        if a[i] < minVal {
            minVal := a[i];
        } else if a[i] > maxVal {
            maxVal := a[i];
        }
    }

    diff := maxVal - minVal;
}

function Min(a: seq<int>) : int
    requires |a| > 0
{
    if |a| == 1 then a[0]
    else if a[0] <= Min(a[1..]) then a[0] else Min(a[1..])
}

function Max(a: seq<int>) : int
    requires |a| > 0
{
    if |a| == 1 then a[0]
    else if a[0] >= Max(a[1..]) then a[0] else Max(a[1..])
}
```

This doesn't verify.

I know I can rewrite the method like this:

```
method DifferenceMinMax(a: array<int>) returns (diff: int)
    requires a.Length > 0
    ensures diff == (Max(a[..]) - Min(a[..]))
{
    var minVal := Min(a[..]);
    var maxVal := Max(a[..]);

    diff := maxVal - minVal;
}
```

This verifies. But this traverses the array twice, while the first iterative solution does it only once. Assume I really want the first iterative algorithm. How do I define Max and Min so that the returned diff is really the difference between the max and the min?

I already tried this, which I was hoping to use in the loop invariant somehow, but it doesn't verify:

```
function Min(a: seq<int>) : (m: int)
    requires |a| > 0
    ensures forall n :: n in a ==> m in a && m <= n
{
    if |a| == 1 then a[0]
    else if a[0] <= Min(a[1..]) then a[0] else Min(a[1..])
}
```

Do I need to get rid of the functions entirely?
Thanks.

Comment: In second approach there is obvious relation between minVal and Min(a[..]) but that is not obvious in iterative version. Two function/methods can compute same value but implementation might differ. You have to connect two using specification (here no specification i.e. ensures clause exits in Max/Min so dafny is not able to reason)

Comment: Adding specification to Min is right step towards goal now try to connect minVal with Min function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question.

Here is some advice on how to solve such an issue, and below is the solution

***Advice***

- In your loop, you effectively compute `min(min(min(a[0], a[1]), a[2]), a[3])`. Looking at that, it is best practice to ensure your specification of the minimum matches this computation. Your current spec computes `min(a[0], min(a[1], min(a[2]....)))` so you'll have a hard time (meaning, needing a lemma) to prove that the two are the same, or postconditions (I haven't tried that)
- If a for loop is failing to verify (i.e. some invariants), it's better to convert it temporarily to a while loop and explicit the assignments of the loop variable
- Write the invariant as an assertion that should hold at the end of the for loop
- Apply the [weakest precondition calculus](https://dafny.org/dafny/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-verification-debugging) to see what should hold at the beginning
- In your min and max function, you compute the same function twice, you can assign it to a variable
- You need to have an invariant that produces something about MinVal(a) and MaxVal(a) at the end.

That advice given, here is the solution.

*** Solution ***

```
method DifferenceMinMax(a: array<int>) returns (diff: int)
    requires a.Length > 0
    ensures diff == (Max(a[..]) - Min(a[..]))
{
    var minVal := a[0];
    var maxVal := a[0];
    for i := 1 to a.Length
        invariant 1 <= i <= a.Length
        invariant minVal <= maxVal
        invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < i ==> minVal <= a[k] && a[k] <= maxVal
        invariant minVal == Min(a[..i])
        invariant maxVal == Max(a[..i])
    {
        if a[i] < minVal {
            minVal := a[i];
        } else if a[i] > maxVal {
            maxVal := a[i];
        }
        assert a[..i+1][..i] == a[..i];
    }
    assert a[..a.Length] == a[..];
    diff := maxVal - minVal;
}

function Min(a: seq<int>) : (m: int)
    requires |a| > 0
{
    if |a| == 1 then a[0]
    else
      var minPrefix := Min(a[..|a|-1]);
      if a[|a|-1] <= minPrefix then a[|a|-1] else minPrefix
}

function Max(a: seq<int>) : (m: int)
    requires |a| > 0
{
    if |a| == 1 then a[0]
    else
      var maxPrefix := Max(a[..|a|-1]);
      if a[|a|-1] >= maxPrefix then a[|a|-1] else maxPrefix
}
```

Comment: Enlightening! So, if the order of a recursive function matches the order of the iteration, Dafny is capable of matching the traversal? That is an eye-opener!
The other eyeopener is those two asserts you included. I've encountered those situations before, and never thought of asserting these "obvious" statements.
Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: Yes and that's avoiding every problem !